# Looking for name of book where main character is learning magic from very old wizard

Tags: story-identification, magic, immortality

Character is trying to learn magic from very old wizard. It turns out the wizard is hurting his students when they are ready to graduate. Main character defeats the wizard because he is his son and they share the same secret name. The reason was that the father wanted to place his soul in the son's body but the son had been saved by his mother.

Comment: Do you remember when you read this? Was it a paper or an electronic book? Paperback or hardback? What language was it in?

Comment: Do you know any of the characters names or a word in the title?

Comment: "book where main character is learning magic from very old wizard" - Every fantasy novel ever.

Comment: With some mental squinting this could even describe the plot of Tim Powers' *Last Call*.  Though I don't think that's the answer.  We're going to need a little more detail here.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat reminiscent of [The Scion of Abacus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0089P70UQ).

> The character is the son of a thousand+ year old wizard, who serially kills and takes over the bodies of his offspring to extend his own life.

I don't recall enough details to remember if the mother comes in though.  This is also a fairly recent book so it may not match depending on your timeframe.

Answer (score -2):

Erragorn, although its the later one of the three books.

Comment: Hi, could you add anything to explain why you think it's Erragorn/Eragon. I honestly don't know, so can't judge, but I highly respect Adamant's opinion which makes me feel that it would be very worthwhile for you to provide some supporting evidence. Welcome to the site, by the way! :)

Comment: Areou are referring to the Eragon series? There are 4 books but I do not recall anyone using their offspring to extend their life.